# Changing star rating by using jQuery UI slider with Fontawesome

Tags: jquery, html, css, uislider, rating-system

I want to change the star items in top right when slider value changes, For example when the slider value is 1 there should be 1 star, for value 2 there should be 2 star and so on up-to 5 star keeping the same html structure if possible. I kept the `slide: function() {}`empty because I don't know how to make the function when the value changes.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.slider-rating').slider({
    range: true,
    min: 1,
    max: 5,
    values: [3, 5],
    slide: function() {

    }
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');
@import
url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.2/css/font-awesome.min.css');
@import 
url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.css');

.control-group {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 50px 20px;
}

.control-group .controls {
 margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="control-group">
  <div class="control-top clearfix">
    <div class="control-title pull-left">Ratings</div>
    <div class="control-percentage pull-right">
      <span class="slider-rating-label">
        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="controls">
    <div class="slider slider-rating"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Added two stars and then I did this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.slider-rating').slider({
    range: true,
    min: 1,
    max: 5,
    values: [3, 5],
    slide: function(x,y) {
        var stars = $('.slider-rating-label').find('i');
        //clear all
        $.each(stars, function (index, value) {
            $(value).removeClass().addClass('fa fa-star-o');
        });
        //fill by slider value
        for (var i = 0; i < y.value; i++) {
            $(stars[i]).removeClass().addClass('fa fa-star');
        }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this, but actually I am not looking this result. Instead of fa-star-o I'm looking to change in html `<i class="fa fa-star"></i>`, if value is 1 then 1 fa-star, if value is 2 then 2 fa-star, if value is 3 then 3 fa-star in html, up-to 5 fa-star for value 5.